# Seg fault core dumped when assigning char** to empty array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, c-strings

Here is my code: the line pipeArr[i] = commands leads to a seg fault core dumped.

```
char ***pipeArr;
for (int i = 0; i < numPipes; i++) {
    char** commands = /* a function that returns char** */
    pipeArr[i] = commands;
}
```

Why does assigning a char** array to the index of an unassigned char*** array lead to a seg fault? Is there any way I can prevent this?

Comment: Don't use uninitialized variables. In particular, do not dereference uninitialized pointers.

Comment: `pipeArr` is not an array, it is a pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You never assigned any value to `pipeArr`, so it's a pointer to nothing in particular. So when you do `pipeArr[i] = ...` you are modifying the `i`'th element of nothing of particular.

Comment: But in particular an attempt to modify an address in memory at some location over which his program no right to access or modify `:)`